# How to concatenate specific tensors in a list of torch.tensors along a particular dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch

Suppose I have a list of torch tensors: 16 tensors in a list, each tensor of size (10,5).

I need to concatenate every 8th tensor in the list along dim=1.

At the end I want a list with 8 tensors, each tensor of size (10, 10).

I have tried this using for loop, torch.cat, list.append functions, but is time consuming.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Whats wrong with the for loop?